# Constructively generate the set of sequences of non-negative integers with finitely many non-zero elements

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S_{l} = \{(a_1, a_2, \dots ) \,|\, a_i\in \mathbb{N}_0$} be the set of sequences of non-negative integers such that only finitely many of the $a_i$ are non-zero.

This set is countable as follows: each such sequence can be mapped to an integer as
$$(a_1, a_2,\dots) \to \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i}$$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

I am looking for a direct, constructive way to generate $S_l$ other than reverting to the above mapping. Ideally, given any element of $S_l$, I would like to have an algorithm to generate the (or a) next element of $S_l$. The problem I have is that I see three "dimensions" on which an escape to infinity must be limited in each step:

1. Each non-zero value can be counted to infinity.
2. The number of leading zero elements and the number of zero elements between the non-zero elements can be extended to infinity.
3. The number of non-zero elements can be extended to infinity.

EDIT: given a hint in the comments, this is what I have so far:

- fix an upper bound on the $a_i$, say K
- fix the index N such that $a_i=0\, \forall i>N$
- generate all $(a_1,\dots,a_N, 0, \dots)$ with $0\leq a_i\leq K$ and $a_N>0$. This is a finite set and can "easily" (details left as an exercise :-)) be generated.
- increment $N$, then $K$ and in between repeat the above, carefully avoiding to generate sequences that were generated already.

As suggested in a comment, using $K=N$ might do too.

I'll toy around with some approaches and see if I can find something elegant to create the next sequence given a sequence $(a_1,\dots)$ and might eventually post my own answer. If someone has neat idea, let me know.

Comment: Can you say some more about the context? Do you want a specification of a primitive recursive function? Or a practical implementation? Or some kind of pseudo-code? Or what? You can get by with just two dimensions: an upper bound on the number of non-zero entries and an upper bound on the entries and you can take these to be equal. You can then give an algoithm that given the current value of the bound and the last sequence, calculates the next sequence subject to the current bound, if there is one, or increments the bound and calculates the next sequence subject to the new bound if not.

Comment: I would accept this already as an answer. I missed the fact that I can reduce the upper bounds to take care of to just one instead of three. See EDIT.